# Python search for an exact string in a file

Tags: python, regex, search

```
import re

def find_string(file_name, word):
   with open(file_name, 'r') as a:
       for line in a:
           line = line.rstrip()
           if re.search("^{}$".format(word),line):
             return True
   return False

if find_string('/tmp/myfile', 'hello'):
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

myfile:

```
hello world #does not match
hello #match
```

If I remove ^ and $ then it will match but it will also match "he","hel" etc. How can I match the exact string if there are multiples words on a single line?

Comment: Can you expand on what you are trying to match? If you want to match a line that is exactly `word`, then `line.rstrip() == word` will do.

Comment: Use word boundaries `\bhello\b`. Please see [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/DF45OY/2)

Comment: That's a good point. Are you trying to match a single word in a line? if you are just trying to match string "hel" in "hello world", well, its there. That is a proper match.

Comment: It sounds like you want _whole words_, not _exact strings_.

Comment: Try: `if re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(word),line):` and note the `r` before the regex string which makes sure the backslashes are interpreted correctly.

Comment: We can't solve this problem if you don't respond to questions.

Comment: using word boundary worked! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may try using [**word-boundaries**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) around your text. Something like:

```
\bhello\b
```

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/DF45OY/2)

**Sample implementation in Python**

```
import re
def find_string(file_name, word):
   with open(file_name, 'r') as a:
       for line in a:
           line = line.rstrip()
           if re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(word),line):
             return True
   return False

if find_string('myfile.txt', 'hello'):
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

You can find the sample run of the above implementation in [**here.**](https://repl.it/@mAndY80SS/TruthfulHumongousWeblogsoftware)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this? Sorry if not

```py
import re

with open('regex.txt', 'r') as a:
    word = "hello"
    for line in a:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if re.search(r"({})".format(word), line):
            print(f'{line} ->>>> match!')
        else:
            print(f'{line} ->>>> not match!')
```

```
text file:
hello world #does not match
hello #match
test here
teste hello here

[output]
hello world #does not match ->>>> match!
hello #match ->>>> match!
test here ->>>> not match!
teste hello here ->>>> match!
```